# Wordpress on HPHP

Tags: php, c++, wordpress, hiphop

I have seen that is indeed possible to compile Wordpress with HPHP and was wondering... how much faster does it actually make it? I know that HPHP works fastest when it comes to static sites but would it make running Wordpress for major sites significantly faster?

I know at the same time that it makes the one-click-upgrade and theme development harder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last year, Rasmus Lerdorf, a core member of the PHP team, [made this presentation at the Digg offices](http://about.digg.com/blog/rasmus-lerdorf-php-performance) in which he tries to make Wordpress compile under HPHP... after doing his own work to make it fast as he can.

You don't need to watch the video, [the slides are enlightening enough](http://talks.php.net/show/digg).

The ***tl;dr*** is that proof-based optimization of code using proper tools will get you a great speed increase without the hassle of HPHP.  Oh, and you need to modify Wordpress anyway to get it to compile, as it uses extensions that HPHP does not replicate.